# Expect +to VS expect + ing

Tags: word-choice, verbs, infinitives, gerunds

I know that expect is used this way:

> I expect you to do that.

But I have also seen examples like with verb in its "ing" form:

> What to expect working at...
>
> I will expect you doing (does not sound right to me)

I would be grateful for explanation.

Comment: https://www.google.com/q=site:english.stackexchange.com+ing+gerund

Answer (score 9):

The verb *to expect* always takes an infinitive complement:

> I expect it to rain.
>
> They expect us to present tomorrow.

This is the normal way of forming sentences with *expect*. Your last example above is, as you suspected, grammatically incorrect:

> *I will expect you doing well.

The other example that you gave with *expect + -ing* is something else. In this case., the verb *working* is the beginning of an adverbial phrase, and isn't a complement to *expect* at all.

> Here's what to expect working at BigCorp.

In this sentence *what to expect* is a nominal relative clause indicating what you should expect, and *working at BigCorp* is an adverbial gerund indicating where you will be working.

Other examples can be constructed that put *expect* and a gerund together, but in all of those examples the gerund is not a complement to *expect*, but an independent grammatical phrase which just happens to come close to *expect*. The actual complement of *expect* is always an infinitive.

Answer (score 3):

*Expect* can occur with an [Infinitive Object Complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf), either with an [Equi](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) subject:

- ***A*** Configuration: *Bill expects [for Bill] to do that.* ==> *Bill expects to do that.*

or with a different NP appearing as subject in the complement

- ***B*** Configuration: *Bill expects [for] Mary to do that.* ==> *Bill expects Mary to do that.*

But it **can't** occur with a Gerund complement:

- **Bill expects [Bill]'s doing that*. ==> **Bill expects doing that.*
- **Bill expects Mary('s) doing that.*  ==> **Bill expects Mary('s) doing that.*

That's why **I will expect you doing ...* sounds bad to you. It **is** bad.

What's going on with

> *This is what you should expect working at SlimeCo.*

is that the gerund clause is not a complement (Noun) clause, but a reduced Adverb clause, which can appear in many places in a sentence, but which happens to appear here right after *expect*, exactly where a complement would appear. Score one for English syntax.

- *This is what you should expect, **[while you are]** working at SlimeCo.*
- ***[While you are]*** working at SlimeCo, this is what you should expect.